# Something wrong with my mySQL query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t.id, t.active, t.off, t.duration, t.user
FROM table t
WHERE t.active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
OR t.duration != '0'
AND t.user = '1'
AND t.off = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Basically it's ignoring the t.off part, whats wrong?

Thank you =)

(the query was edited for an example purpose, the real query is similar to this but with other table names, etc)

== [ Update ] ==

```
SELECT t.active, t.off, t.duration, t.user
FROM table t
WHERE (
    t.active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    OR t.duration != '0'
)
AND t.user = '1'
AND t.off = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
UNION ALL
SELECT c.active, c.off, c.duration, c.user
FROM chair c
WHERE (
    c.active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    OR c.duration != '0'
)
AND c.user = '1'
AND c.off = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parenthesis, to group conditions *(`and` / `or`)*, to make sure they are evaluated in the order you want.

For example, do you want to following :

```
SELECT t.id, t.active, t.off, t.duration, t.user
FROM table t
WHERE t.active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
OR (
    t.duration != '0'
    AND t.user = '1'
    AND t.off = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Or the following :

```
SELECT t.id, t.active, t.off, t.duration, t.user
FROM table t
WHERE (
    t.active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    OR t.duration != '0'
)
AND t.user = '1'
AND t.off = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Or maybe something else ?

Using parenthesis will make your query easier to read -- and will help making sure the conditions are evaluated properly.

Comment: FYI, MySQL interprets this as the first one.  In short, non-parenthesis'd or's group all and's around them:  `a and b or c and d and e` => `(a and b) or (c and d and e)`

Comment: Basically, I want to select where active is nothing OR duration is not 0, so basically active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR duration = '1' - after that, I want to select them for X user and I only want results where off is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' also. Is your second answer this? It seems to work. Please confirm. Thank you ! :)

Comment: @Kyle if I understand what you want correctly, the second example I posted should be the one you're looking for, yes. @cwolves thanks for the clarification !

Comment: Using the second mySQL code you provided, it made a result disappear where active = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', off = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and duration = '1' - this should be showing as duration is 1, as declared in the OR?

Comment: hu... maybe the user is not 1 ?

Comment: It is, it may be because I'm doing two tables in one, I will post the full query in the question for you to view.